# accept multi line string in Process.Start

Tags: c#, string, process

i am parsing a path from a directory location:

assuming that `InitialPath = @"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects"`

and i have a loop of:

```
var list = new List<string>();

foreach(var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(InitialPath) {
    var folder = Path.GetFileName(folder);
    var file = Path.GetFileName(Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.sln").Single());

    list.Add(InitialPath +  "\\" + folder + "\\" + file); //would then result something like "C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Folder1\Project1inFolder1.sln"
}
```

if i try a path from the `list` and assign it to a `richbox` as its `.text` value, it returns a single line text.

[image]

but when i'm displaying it on a `MessageBox`, the string is being broken into two lines as below:

[image]

i need to force it not to be broken into several lines. i mean, i need it to be a single line string only no matter the length of the string because `Process.Start()` wont accept the string because it gets cut into lines. see below for reference:

[image]

`PS: sorry for not being able to explain my question eligibly, english is not my natural language`

just in case, here is my code snippet:

```
using MaterialSkin;
using MaterialSkin.Controls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace The_Projects {
    public partial class MainForm : MaterialForm {
        public MainForm() {
            InitializeComponent();

            var materialSkinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
            materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
            materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.LIGHT;
            materialSkinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(Primary.BlueGrey800, Primary.BlueGrey900, Primary.BlueGrey500, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.WHITE);
        }

        public class DirectoryInformation {
        private string _FolderName;
        private string _Solution;
        private DateTime _Created;
        private DateTime _Accessed;
        private DateTime _Modified;
        private string _SecIdentity;
        private string _NTAccount;
        private double _FileSize;
        private int _FileCount;

        public string FolderName {
            get { return _FolderName; }
            set { _FolderName = value; }
        }

        public string Solution {
            get { return _Solution; }
            set { _Solution = value; }
        }

        public DateTime Created {
            get { return _Created; }
            set { _Created = value; }
        }

        public DateTime Accessed {
            get { return _Accessed; }
            set { _Accessed = value; }
        }

        public DateTime Modified {
            get { return _Modified; }
            set { _Modified = value; }
        }

        public string SecIdentity {
            get { return _SecIdentity; }
            set { _SecIdentity = value; }
        }

        public string NTAccount {
            get { return _NTAccount; }
            set { _NTAccount = value; }
        }

        public double FileSize {
            get { return _FileSize; }
            set { _FileSize = value; }
        }

        public int FileCount {
            get { return _FileCount; }
            set { _FileCount = value; }
        }
    }

        public string InitialPath = @"X:\_\Document\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\";
        public string FolderPath = string.Empty;
        public string Solution = string.Empty;

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var projectList = new List<DirectoryInformation>();

            foreach(var dirs in Directory.GetDirectories(InitialPath)) {
                var ac = File.GetAccessControl(dirs);
                var di = new DirectoryInfo(dirs);

                var dirInf = new DirectoryInformation() {
                    FolderName = Path.GetFileName(dirs),
                    Solution = Path.GetFileName(Directory.GetFiles(dirs, "*.sln").Single()),
                    Created = Directory.GetCreationTime(dirs),
                    Accessed = Directory.GetLastAccessTime(dirs),
                    Modified = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(dirs),
                    SecIdentity = ac.GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)).ToString(),
                    NTAccount = ac.GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString(),
                    FileSize = (double) di.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(x => x.Length) / 1024000,
                    FileCount = Directory.GetFiles(dirs, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count()
                };

                projectList.Add(dirInf);
            }

            lstProjectList.DataSource = projectList;
            lstProjectList.DisplayMember = "FolderName";
        }

        private void lstProjectList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var project = lstProjectList.SelectedValue as DirectoryInformation;

            lblFolder.Text = project.FolderName;
            lblCreated.Text = project.Created.ToString();
            lblAccess.Text = project.Accessed.ToString();
            lblModified.Text = project.Modified.ToString();
            lblIdentifier.Text = project.SecIdentity;
            lblOwner.Text = project.NTAccount;
            lblSize.Text = project.FileSize.ToString("F2") + " MB";
            lblCount.Text = project.FileCount.ToString();

            FolderPath = InitialPath + project.FolderName;
            Solution = FolderPath + "\\" + project.Solution;
        }

        private void btnOpenProject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe", Solution);
            //Clipboard.SetText(Solution);
        }

        private void btnOpenFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Process.Start("explorer.exe", FolderPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it just the way it's displayed that is showing 2 lines? The string itself should still be a single line, right?

Comment: true, but the way i see how the `Process.Start()` parses the string, it gets cut up into several lines. see the last image reference.

Comment: Put a break point on `process.Start()` and see what it's accepting as input.

Comment: it shows a single line of text, but when the `Process.Start()` is executed, it gets cut into several lines.

http://i.imgur.com/heESvNH.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the way your MessageBox is wrapping text. You've got two options here:

- Create a custom Forms class
- Create a form dialog just for showing messages

EDIT:

Change this:

```
 Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe", Solution);
```

to

```
 Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe", "\"" + Solution + "\"");
```

What's happening here is the second parameter to the `Process.Start` method is treated as argument(s) for the executable given by the first parameter. So what process.start does is the equivalent (but not quite the same) of opening the command prompt and typing out:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" X:\_\Document\Visual Studio 2015\.....
```

and the command prompt treats (space) as a parameter separator, so it treats `X:\_\Document\Visual` as one parameter, `Studio` as the next and so on. When you use `"\""` around the string you're telling Process.Start that the whole thing (including spaces) is a single parameter.

Comment: the question was not about the messagebox showing a multi line of text. my question was how can `Process.Start()` accept this multi line of string ?

Comment: I think you need escaped double quotes around `Solution`. I'm guessing that the solution path is the single parameter to `@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe". If there are spaces in the parameter, it treats them as separate parameters.

Comment: i have no problems with the first parameter, and yes i've escaped the path to devenv.exe.

the issue now is the second parameter, which is the path to the file to be opened using parameter 1.

Comment: `Solution` is the second parameter, isn't it. I've edited my answer to reflect what i just said.

Comment: wow, it worked. could you explain me how it managed to get through ?. what that `"\""` is, what its for, and how it works ? thanks

Comment: no wait, i get it how it works. it's like adding double quotes in the beginning and the end of the location string right ?. sorry, but thanks :)

Comment: Yep...changed my answer to explain since it'd be too verbose for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample had some bugs in it, for me this worked and I got all *.sln files

```
//this is just to show that you can get short file name if you need FileInfo
        var list = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        var files = Directory.GetFiles(InitialPath, "*.sln", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
            list.Add(fileInfo.Name, file);
        }

        Process.Start(list.FirstOrDefault().Value);
```

On my computer starts with no problems. 
But if you want a devenv.exe start with a solution open you do it like so

```
 Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe", @"devenv/""" + fullFilePath + @"""");
```

you need the command in arguments devenv/ and you must you must enclose paths in double quotation marks ("fullFilePath").